# Find exact location of a wire inside wall

Tags: electrical, wiring, doorbell

Trying to wire a doorbell. I found an existing hole from the basement going into part of the front door frame.

The house was re-sided by the prior owner and they did not have any doorbell installed at all, so I can run a camera probe up the hole in the basement and see up but can’t tell where this would be on the outside of the house.

Is there a tool or something I can use that would let me find the exact location from the outside of the house? I can see when running the probe the hole is not that big, so if I’m off by an inch or so I miss the hole.

I have a current detector and was trying to detect the current from the camera from upstairs but that didn’t work. I think i need to create a stronger signal. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: it would be covered (hidden) in a typical door bell location, half a way up on the right side of the door. The Voltage meter (not current) would show 12- 18 Volt on the wires

Comment: What would be "covered (hidden)" in a typical door bell location? Is half-way up on the right side some sort of code requirement or your convention or...? That seems awfully specific and yet totally random. Wouldn't the doorbell most likely be on the knob side of the door opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in fact trying to locate the cavity in the wall, not a pre-existing wire in the wall (you've just thought of detecting the camera cable you can poke into it first):

Tape a rare earth magnet to the end of a stick and poke it into the hole, leaned against the outside wall from the inside. Go looking outside with a bit of steel/iron and look for the spot on the wall where the steel/iron sticks to the wall (or at least has "noticeable attraction" to the wall, depending on thickness of siding, etc.)

@Jasen's idea of using a compass will probably work even better, being more sensitive (so working through thicker material.)

You COULD use a toner/tracer set sometimes referred to as "Fox & Hound" which is one brand of the type) with a cable poked into the cavity - but unless you own such a set already (I assume not, or you would have thought of it and tried it) that's a relatively expensive approach and a tool most people have few uses for.

Your camera cable is probably shielded to prevent noise getting in or out, making it difficult to detect.

Comment: The “toner/tracer” is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: seriouly a magnet an a pocket compass will be more accurate than the tone tracer.